# MariaDB / MySQL : Insert select into in trigger does not insert anything

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a after insert trigger on `vitamin` to insert the new data into `vitamin_variety` with cross join select statement that I created. But somehow when new rows are inserted, the trigger does not insert that new rows into `vitamin_variety`. I use select statements with join and it works good on it's own but when I use it to insert into select statement, it does nothing.

My code

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO 
vitamin_variety (extreme_name,regular_name, price_variety_extreme,price_variety_regular) 

SELECT sel_extreme.name as `extreme_name`,sel_regular.name as `regular_name`,sel_extreme.ext,sel_regular.reg FROM

(SELECT sel.name as `name`,sel.id as `id`,sel.extreme as `ext` FROM
(SELECT new.vitamin_name as `name`,new.vitamin_id as `id`,CASE WHEN new.vitamin_name LIKE 'extreme%' THEN new.price END AS `extreme`
FROM vitamin) AS sel
WHERE sel.extreme IS NOT NULL) AS sel_extreme

CROSS JOIN

(SELECT sel.name as `name`,sel.id as `id`, sel.regular as `reg` FROM
(SELECT new.vitamin_name as `name`,new.vitamin_id as `id`,CASE WHEN new.vitamin_name NOT LIKE 'extreme%' THEN new.price END AS `regular`
FROM vitamin) AS sel
WHERE sel.regular IS NOT NULL) AS sel_regular

WHERE sel_regular.id <= sel_extreme.id
END
```

**EDITED**
Here's the [FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kscvizEzNQJpZapqJbt7VY/6)

Comment: *I'm trying to create a after insert trigger* Where are your attempts? complete code of the trigget which you try to use?

Comment: Your last query in the fiddle is wrong - it is not deterministic. And it will fail if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL` mode enabled.

Comment: The fiddle code is not the same as the question code.

Comment: @Akina I have edited my question. I'd appreciate for your review.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have edited my question. I'd appreciate for your review.

Comment: ??? I do not see any correlation between the question and the fiddle. PS. In the fiddle - drop triggers, alter `difference` column and make it generated one.

Comment: sorry @Akina, I did not know I have to update the queries in the fiddle in or der to save it. I have changed the fiddle now, I'd appreciate for your review.

Comment: @littlesheep After code update you'd run the fiddle, ensure it gives proper outputs, and publist new link.